# Replace text in text file using VBS

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have been using Notepad++ to make adjustments to a TXT file. I was wondering if its possible to automate this using VBScript?

- Open the file.
- Replace `\r\n` with " " (a blank space).
- Replace `I0` with `\nI0`.
- Replace `X0` with `\nI0`.
- Save the file.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Why only VBScript? It can be done in number of other ways too. But what exactly are you looking at and what have you done to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example is suitable for Unicode and ASCII text files:

```
sPath = "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\tmp\test.txt"
sContent = ReadTextFile(sPath, 0) ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
sContent = Replace(sContent, vbCrLf, " ")
sContent = Replace(sContent, "I0", vbLf & "I0")
sContent = Replace(sContent, "X0", vbLf & "I0")
WriteTextFile sContent, sPath, 0

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, lFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(sContent, sPath, lFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 2, True, lFormat)
        .Write sContent
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```